# what is the better way for writing unit testing functions in java script

Tags: javascript

In javascript, same functions can be written in different ways such as following. which way is best for unit testing scenarios

```
 // 1st way ============ 
var app = {};
app.name = "abc"
app.init = function () {
    return "test";
};

// 2nd way ============
function app() {
    this.name = "abc";
};
app.prototype.init = function () {
    return "test";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is both easy to test:

```
// 1st way
assert.equal(app.name, 'abc')
assert.equal(app.init(), 'test')

// 2nd way
var appInstance = new app()
assert.equal(appInstance.name, 'abc')
assert.equal(appInstance.init(), 'test')
```

However in the "2nd way" app should be **uppercase** (as Constructors should begin uppercase).

The "1st way" maybe a bit harder to test, since `var app` will have to be exported as global variable and it will be hard to write tests again a mutable global object (side-effects).

Thus **I'd recommend to use the "2nd way"** as you can create a clean test setup be (re-) invoking the ctor in a `beforeEach` (when using mocha):

```
describe('the app'', function() {
  var app
  beforeEach(function() {
    app = new App()
  })

  it(...)
  it(...)
})
```

If you don't like prototypes use can go this way to achieve the same good testability

```
var createApp = function() {
  var app = {};
  app.name = "abc"
  app.init = function () {
   return "test";
  };
  return app;
}
```